# Connect docker-compose container on Mac OS

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

Running docker-compose (1.23.2, build 1110ad01) on Mac OS I am having a hard time getting the IP address of my container. My compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  secondcontainer:
    image: myregistry/secondcontainer
    networks: mynet
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "1.0"
          memory: 500M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "54000:54000"
    networks:
      - mynet
networks:
  mynet:
```

I can see the two containers coming alive, and I can see that something is listening on port 54000

```
com.docke 28032 me   22u  IPv4 0x2b3b4a41c30a8773      0t0  TCP *:54000 (LISTEN)
```

I am trying to access this container using a C# app running on the Mac. No matter what IP address I use, I can't seem to get through. I have tried 127.0.0.1:54000, I have tried the local IP of the Mac host, I have tried the IP address the container is assigned (172.25.0.3 as an example) with the right port. I have tried with nc, no luck there.

Same code works flawlessly on Linux. I know there may be issues with Docker on Mac, but isn't this a supported scenario?

Comment: I think I’ve seen it reported elsewhere that the container-private IP addresses don’t work on Docker for Mac; that’s one of several reasons to just not look them up at all.  I would expect `localhost:54000` to work though.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that. It does not work either. I have enumerated all the potential addresses localhost can evaluate to and tried those, but no luck.

Comment: what is the response that you get when you try to connect ?

Comment: I get no response. I can't see the connection actually making it through (the container will write to the logs that it has accepted a connection), I see no response when I try to write to the tcp stream, only a hang when I wait for a response from the container.

Comment: David, I am not per se interested in the IP address, I am interested in communicating from the outside world (in this case the host) to the container. Surely, that should be possible?